# Insert/get múltiplas tabelas sem Id

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com um problema me afetando alguns dias ja. A situação é o seguinte, eu tenho um relacionamento simples: Existem as tabelas pessoa, rua, bairro, cidade, estado, pais todas montadas a partir de classes Hibernate usando o JPA. Na modelagem a pessoa tem o código da rua, rua o código do bairro e vai indo até chegar em pais.
No Relacionamento entre essas entidades eu utilizei a anotação `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)` para inserir no banco caso nao existe e se existir ele nao inserir nada e apenas pegar o ID do ja inserido. Esse é o problema, eu consigo inserir normalmente, mas ele cria uma linha para cada pessoa, mas eu quero inserir apenas o que é novo, exemplo:

Eu quero que se já exista por exemplo, "Brasil" no Pais, ele não insira um novo registro duplicado na tabela Pais mas sim pegue o id do que já tem e continue o processo fazendo o mesmo procedimento para as outras entidades abaixo desta (Já tem o estado pega o id na base, já tem cidade pega o id na base,não tem bairro insere a linha colocando o id da cidade, não tem rua insere colocando o id do bairro). Com o JDBC eu fiz isso facilmente utilizando de selects, mas creio eu que no Hibernate/JPA posso fazer mais facilmente.

Neste caso, eu recebo do usuário os dados do endereço preenchidos, mas sem os Ids, então eu teria que fazer essa busca no banco pela string do endereço e não pelo id,

Segue o código:

```
@Entity(name = "FUNCIONARIO")
public class Funcionario implements Serializable
{

 /*Variaveis*/

 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
 @JoinColumn
 @Valid
 private Rua rua;
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn
 private Departamento departamento;

 /*ToString() + Getters e Setters*/ 
}
```

Classe Rua:

```
@Entity(name = "RUA")
public class Rua implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long codRua;
  @NotEmpty
  private String nomeRua;
  @NotEmpty
  private String cep;
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
  @JoinColumn
  @Valid
  private Bairro bairro;

 /*ToString() + Getters e Setters*/ 
}
```

Classe Bairro:

```
@Entity(name = "BAIRRO")
public class Bairro implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long codBairro;
  @NotEmpty
  private String nomeBairro;
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
  @JoinColumn
  @Valid
  private Cidade cidade;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bairro", targetEntity = Rua.class, 
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Rua> ruas;

 /*ToString() + Getters e Setters*/ 
}
```

A inserção no banco eu dou um `entityManager.merge(Funcionario);`

E o procedimento dos `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)` seguem até a ultima classe que seria Pais. Vocês podem me dar uma luz de como prosseguir?

Edit 1:

Esse é o objeto que eu recebo do usuário:

```
Funcionario{codFuncionario=3, nomeCompleto=Jhonatan Colina, dataNascimento=Tue Apr 30 00:00:00 BRT 1996, cpf=212.132.312-13, rg=21.321.213-2, orgaoEmissor=SSP-sp, email=jhonatan.nascimento@outlook.com, emailAlternativo=jhonatan.nascimento@outlook.com, telefone=(23) 12132-3121, numeroCasa=0000, situacao=true, observacoes=, rua=Rua{codRua=null, nomeRua=Avenida Prefeito Ângelo Celeguim, cep=07809000, bairro=Bairro{codBairro=null, nomeBairro=Vila Santista, cidade=Cidade{codCidade=null, nomeCidade=Franco da Rocha, estado=Estado{codEstado=null, nomeEstado=SP, pais=Pais{codPais=null, nomePais=Brasil}}}}}, departamento=Departamento{codDepartamento=1, nomeDepartamento=null, telefone=null, telefoneComercial=null, situacao=false, secretaria=null}}
```

Comment: Todas as entidades estão sendo duplicadas ou apenas `Pais`? Você tem um código de exemplo mostrando como você está buscando as entidades, associando ao funcionário e atualizando ele?

Comment: Vc quer que o hibernate busque automaticamente os registros com base nos valores fornecidos e persista com os registros existentes ou, caso não exista, crie os registros?